# Derivation of Ohm's law using classical and quantum model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electrical-resistance

How can I derive [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) using classical and quantum model? Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. This is not a homework automation site.  Show some attempts to solve by yourself.

Comment: Do you know the [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model)?

Answer (score 2):

The derivation given here is appropriate for single particle Quantum Mechanics and seeks to derive Ohm's law in the form:
$$
j_i = \sigma_{ij}E_j\;, 
$$ 
where $j_i$ is the ith component of the current (density) and E_j is the jth component of the electric field and $\sigma_{ij}$ is the conductivity (tensor).

By definition we have the current operator:
$$
\hat {j_i} = q \hat v_i = \frac{q}{m}\hat p_i\;,
$$
where $\hat p$ is the momentum operator, q is the charge, m is the mass, and the current (not the current operator) is:
$$
j_i(t) = \langle\Psi(t)|\hat{j_i}|\Psi(t)\rangle\;,
$$
where $\Psi$ is the QM state.

We now solve for the state in the *interaction picture* (as opposed to the Heisenberg picture or the Schrodinger picture). The hamiltonian is decomposed as $H=H_0+V(t)$ where $V$ is the interaction Hamiltonian and $H_0$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian whose ground state we call $|0\rangle$. Then, to first order in the interaction, the interaction picture state is:
$$
|\Psi^I(t)\rangle = |0\rangle - i\int^t dt' V^I(t')|0\rangle\;,
$$ 
where
$$
V^I(t) = e^{iH_0t}V(t)e^{-iH_0t}\;.
$$

Now, let's specialize to a interaction that is *linear* in the *spacially constant* field $\vec E$:
$$
V = -qf(t)\vec E\cdot \vec r\;.
$$
N.b., remember that $-\nabla\phi = E$. The time dependent part $f(t)$ can be something like $\sin(\omega_0 t)$ or whatever other pure time dependence we like.

So, keeping enough terms in the expansion of the state to solve for j to first order in E, we have:
$$
j_i =\left(\langle0|-iqE_j\int^t dt'f(t')\langle 0| \hat r^I_j(t')\right)
\frac{q}{m}\hat p_i
\left(|0\rangle+iqE_j\int^t dt'f(t')\hat r^I_j(t')|0\rangle\right)
$$
Or:
$$
j_i = \sigma_{ij}E_j\;,
$$
where
$$
\sigma_{ij} = \frac{-iq^2}{m}\int^t dt'f(t')\langle0|[r^I_j(t'),p_i]|0\rangle\;.
$$

This specific relationship between j and E also is based on the assumption that there is no current in the unperturbed ground state $|0\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law can be shown true from a classical model if we show or demonstrate that the electric field on a charge moving at a constant velocity through the conductor is directly proportional to it's average 'drift' velocity or drift speed rather. Of course, motion that is not in the direction of applied emf will not do work overall so no voltage is transferred overall. In other words, electrical potential energy transfers from 'heat to heat'.

Take $E$ as the resistive electric field, $v$ as the drift velocity and $q$ as free charge density in coulombs per meter cubed. $I,V$ are current and voltage lost to heat between two points in the conductor and $dL$ is the distance between the two points.

$E=\frac{F}{q} = kv$

$I = vAq$

$V=E\cdot{dL}=I\frac{dL}{Aq}k$ where $\frac{k}{q}$ is resistivity.

I should add that the initial assumption can be crudely derived by applying newton's second law to the charge carries and setting up a homogenous wire which applies static (coulombic) electrical repulsion force. The situation here is comparable to drag causing a falling object to reach terminal velocity and using that velocity to deduce the energy transfer, but it's not the same. Electrodynamics is not quite the same as newtonian classical mechanics in most cases.